# How do you make a program wait for user input?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, actionlistener

I'd like to use the variable `column_input` later.

```
public static void playGame(){   
    btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String input = textField.getText();
            chosen_column = Integer.parseInt(input);
            textField.setText(null);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: how much wait you want to put for user input?

Comment: Use a modal dialog

Comment: 1) *"I'd like to use the variable `column_input` later."* There is no attribute named `column_input` in that code snippet. 2) Rather than parsing text input to an integer, offer the user a `JSpinner` using a `SpinnerNumberModel`. Query the value of the model after the dialog mentioned by @MadProgrammer has been dismissed (directly after `dialog.setVisible(true);`) - like this `int number = model.getNumber().intValue();`

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you only need a single piece of data. The easiest solution is to use a `JOptionPane`. You can prompt for user input.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Make Dialogs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html) for more information and working examples to get you started.